# UIView with gradient layer not conforming to constraints set

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, cagradientlayer

In `viewDidLoad`, I instantiate a `UIView` and add a gradient layer to that UIView.

This works well on iPhone, but on iPad, `UIView` does not stretch out to fill the entire screen. Please note the following screenshot for iPad sim.

[iPad simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0147.png)

I have attempted adding constraints both programmatically and by using XCode.

It seems that once I add the CAGradientLayer, the UIView does not conform to the constraints that I set, either programmatically or using XCode tools.

Sample Code:

```
gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
gradientLayer.locations = [0.5, 1.0]
gradient_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
let color1 = self.opus_Page_Background_Color.CGColor as CGColorRef
let color4 = self.opus_Page_Tertiary_Color.CGColor as CGColorRef
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color4]
self.gradient_View.frame = self.view.bounds
self.gradient_View.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
gradient_View.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gradient_View, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            leadingConstraint.active = true
            view.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)

let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gradient_View, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            trailingConstraint.active = true
            view.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gradient_View, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
            view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gradient_View, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
            view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

Comment: please remove width constraint as per @arun

Comment: THE SOLUTION was to put the code within `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I kept the constraints arbitrary because I was trying to see if ANY constraints would work, but thank you for those tips as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the last two constraints. Instead of matching width and height, pin it to Top & Bottom. The problem probably is that in viewDidLoad, your view has width = X, height = Y, but that's not the final layout.
If that does not work, try adding it in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have added leading and trailing constraint which means you have got the width of the view. So there is no need to add width constraint at all. Remove width from storyboard or programmatically which ever you are using.
Also i could see a missing top constrai nt. Resolve that also